# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float' problem

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My code as follows:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
# All constant value in the code:
G0 = 0.0000775  # Conductance quantum
v = 0.1           # Bias voltage
Time_of_Loops = 1399951  # Time collected by LabVIEW， unit is ms



# read data:
data = pd.read_csv(\
    'C:\\Users\\fq20881\\OneDrive - University of Bristol\\OneDrive\\Data Analysis\\Data.txt', \
    sep=',', names=['Current', 'Position', 'Current2', 'Time2', 'PZT Voltage'])


data.drop([0, 1], axis=0, inplace=True)
data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
nrows1 = data.shape[0]
print('row number of Current:')
print(nrows1)

data1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Time', 'Conductance'], index=range(0, nrows1))
Speed_Time = Time_of_Loops / (nrows1 * 1000)
data1['Time'] = data1.index * Speed_Time
print(data1)
data1['Conductance'] = data['Current'] / (G0 * v)
print(data1)
```

But it cannot divide a number, the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:\Users\fq20881\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 142, in _na_arithmetic_opresult = expressions.evaluate(op, left, right)
File "C:\Users\fq20881\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py", line 235, in evaluatereturn _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b)  # type: ignore[misc]
File "C:\Users\fq20881\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py", line 69, in _evaluate_standardreturn op(a, b)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'
        

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
        

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/fq20881/OneDrive - University of Bristol/OneDrive/python code/Data Analysis/0 Data Analysis.py", line 32, in <module>

data1['Conductance'] = data['Current'].div(G0 * v)

File "C:\Users\fq20881\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 177, in flex_wrapper

return op(self, other)

File "C:\Users\fq20881\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py", line 65, in new_method return method(self, other)
File "C:\Users\fq20881\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py", line 113, in __truediv__return self._arith_method(other, operator.truediv)
File "C:\Users\fq20881\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4968, in _arith_method result = ops.arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
File "C:\Users\fq20881\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 189, in arithmetic_opres_values = _na_arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
File "C:\Users\fq20881\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 149, in _na_arithmetic_op result = _masked_arith_op(left, right, op)
File "C:\Users\fq20881\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 111, in _masked_arith_op result[mask] = op(xrav[mask], y)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your data column `Current` is of type string. Try this

```
data1['Conductance'] = (data1['Current'].astype(int)).div(G0 * v)
```

Comment: It cannot work: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.00000000048729840000'